# reading multiple sheets in python pandas in order

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

in python pandas 3.3 when we read multiple sheets from input excel, does the for loop returns sheetnames in orderly fashion?
I do not know the number of sheets or the name of the sheets but want to read them in the order they are in the excel

Example:

```
all_sheet_dfs = pd.read_excel(excel_in, None, na_filter=False, header=0)
sheets_list =  all_sheet_dfs.keys()

for sheets in sheets_list:
    sheet_df = all_sheet_dfs[sheets]
    print(sheets)
```

Does this return sheets in the order they are in excel everytime we run?

Comment: why don't you try yourself and see the result? If anything goes wrong then you can edit the question and post the error message.

Comment: I tried few times, I am able to see it in order all the time, but just want to confirm that is it in order always or for loop will take it randomly sometimes.